# Ajax Post method is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I am using jquery ajax and code was working fine untill site is moved to new server and somehow on new server ajax post method is not passing any data via POST method and not giving any response as well. I am using codeigniter framework.

Here's my code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //alert(progressbar.width);
    //alert($('.upload-statusbar').width());
    var c =0;
    var settings = {
    url: "class_name/function_name",
    method: "POST",
    //allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif",
    fileName: "userfile[]",
    multiple: true,
/*  onbeforeSend:function()
    {
        $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled','true');
        alert('upload starts');
    },*/
    onSelect:function()
    {
        //alert("Wait untill image being uploaded !!");
        $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled','true');
        $('#submitBtn').addClass('disabled-button');
        $('.disabled-div').css('display','block');
    },
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        //alert(data);
        c++;
        //alert(c);
        var x = data;
        image = "http://domain.com/folder_name/"+data;
        //alert(x);
        var use_class = data.substr(0, data.lastIndexOf('.'));
        //alert(use_class);
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is 100%</font>");
    },
    afterUploadAll:function()
    {
        alert('all images uploaded');   
    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
    }
}
$("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you ever try add base url into your url setting like '<?php echo base_url();?>class_name/function_name' like this?? Me always facing this problem because the url is not specified correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't the first logical step be to add some ajax error handling? Also, inspect request in browser console network tab for clues

Comment: Thanks every1 for your suggestions but issue as with upload.php in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass full url in ajax url section...
like

url: "http://domain.com/class_name/function_name"

or try below code for ajax image upload...

```
var url = BASE_URL + 'class_name/function_name';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    $('#image').attr('src', BASE_URL + "artefacts/images/site/loading.gif");


    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        /*
         * values that indicate the progression
         * e.loaded
         * e.total
         */

        $('#image').attr('src', BASE_URL + "images/loading.gif");

        $('#image').show();
    };
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0)) {
            // if your server sends a message on upload sucess,
            // get it with xhr.responseText
            //alert(xhr.responseText);

            var responseData = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');

            var dimension = String(width) + 'x' + String(height);

            $('#image).hide();

            // Display error messages on view page starts - 10/12/2014
            if (responseData.error !== null)
            {
                $('#image').attr('src', BASE_URL + "images/Pic.png");

                $('#image').show();
                $('.showMsg').html(responseData.error[0]);
            }

            // Check if image has been uploaded successfully
            if (responseData.success !== null) {

                $('#image').attr('src', BASE_URL + 'images/' + responseData.success[dimension] + '?' + new Date().getTime());

                $('#image').show();

                $('#uploaded_image').val(responseData.success[dimension]);

            }
        }
    };
    // upload success
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('title', file.files[0].name);
    form.append('profile_photo', file.files[0]);

    xhr.send(form);
```

Ignore the line of code which is not relevant to you...